# Derive the inequality $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}\log{(2n)}} > \frac{1}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

How do one derive this

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}\log{(2n)}} > \frac{1}{n}$$

from more fundamental inequalities?

I can see intuitively that this is the case, but I probably have to justify it because I use it in a proof. A justification for the inequlity without calculus will be nice.

$\log{}$ is the natural log.

Btw, do not downvote my question before telling me what's wrong with it.

Kind regards,

Comment: What do you mean by "fundamental"?

Comment: @owovrokfop By this I mean other well known inequalies like $\sqrt{n}>\log{n}$.

Comment: It's false when $n=2.$

Comment: @zhw.
Definitely not false! This is true for alle natrual numbers $n$.

Comment: Please list the "other well known inequalies".

Comment: When $n=2$ you claim $1/(2\ln 4) >1/2?$

Comment: @zhw. 
Try it in a calculate.

Comment: It also fails when $n=1:$ $1/(\sqrt 2\ln 2) <1.$

Comment: @Xenusi The commenters are quite right, what you have is that your inequality is true for all sufficiently large $n$, in this case $n \geq 38$ works, I believe.

Comment: @zhw.
Sorry, I thought we were talking about $\sqrt{n} > \log{n}$.

Comment: @Brahadeesh I think the OP is using base 10 logarithm. In that case the inequality holds for any $n \ge 1$.

Comment: @PierreCarre Possible, but they mention that they are using the "natural log", which is to the base $e$, I take it?

Comment: @Brahadeesh You are correct, I only read through the formulas...

Comment: @PierreCarre
Sorry guys. This post is a huge f*** up from my site.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

You have $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n} \log(2n)} > \frac{1}{n} \iff \sqrt{2n} - 2\log(2n) > 0.$$

Can you compute the derivative of the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x} - 2\log(x)$ to say something about when $f(x) > 0$?

Answer (score 0):

From cross multiplying, we have $n > \sqrt{2n}\log{2n}$. Setting $x = 2n$, we have $x/2 > \sqrt{x}\log{x}$. Dividing both sides by $\sqrt{x}/2$, we have $\sqrt{x} > 2\log{x}$. Raising both sides to the powre $e$, we have $e^{\sqrt{x}} > x^2$. Note the derivative of the LHS is greater than the RHS for all $x>0$, so the LHS is greater than the RHS at all points after $e^{\sqrt{x}} = x^2$. I can't analytically evaluate the value of $x$ at which this occurs, but your desired inequality follows for certain values of $n$.

Comment: In my case $\log{}$ is the natural log.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality fails for at least $5 \le n \le 15$. I tried [plotting](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimum%20value%20of%20x%20-%20sqrt%282x%29*log%282x%29) $f(x) = x - \sqrt{2x}\log(2x)$ and the function is negative for the given range. Please check your claim.